# ライブラリで公開している列挙型クラスの名前を変更したいです。変更前と変更後の

Tags: python

## やりたいこと

自作ライブラリで、列挙型クラスを公開しています。
クラスの名前をより良い名前に変更したいのですが、すでに公開しているクラスなので、変更前の名前も利用できるようにしたいです。

## 質問

以下のコードで、ひとまず変更前の名前も利用できるようになりました。

```
from enum import Enum
class NewColor(Enum):
    """色"""
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

OldColor = NewColor
```

しかし、上記のコードでは以下の要件を満たせません。

- `OldColor.__doc__`に、非推奨である旨のメッセージを追加したい
- `OldColor`を参照した場合（`OldColor.RED`,`OldColor(1)`）は、警告メッセージを出力したい
  この要件を満たすには、どのようなコードを書けばよいでしょうか？

## 補足

通常のクラス場合は、以下のコードで、次の要件を満たせることは分かりました。

- 変更前のクラスの`__doc__`に、非推奨である旨のメッセージを追加する
- 変更前のクラスを使ってインスタンス生成する際に、警告メッセージを出力

```
def moved_class(new_class, old_class_name, old_module_name,
                message=None, version=None, removal_version=None,
                stacklevel=3, category=None):
    # ...
    def decorator(f):

        @six.wraps(f, assigned=_utils.get_assigned(f))
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            _utils.deprecation(out_message, stacklevel=stacklevel,
                               category=category)
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    old_class = type(old_class_name, (new_class,), {})
    old_class.__module__ = old_module_name
    old_class.__init__ = decorator(old_class.__init__)
    return old_class
```

https://opendev.org/openstack/debtcollector/src/branch/master/debtcollector/moves.py#L164 引用

## 環境

- Python3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enum` インスタンスの内容を参照する場合は `__getattribute__()` メソッドをラップします。

```py
from my_color import OldColor, NewColor

warning_message = "`OldColor' has moved to `NewColor'"
def deprecation_warning():
  import warnings
  warnings.warn(
    warning_message, DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=4)
  return True

OldColor.__getattribute__ = (
  lambda cls, name:
    deprecation_warning() and
    super(type(cls), cls).__getattribute__(name)
)

OldColor.__doc__ += f'\nWarning: {warning_message}.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(OldColor.RED)
  print(OldColor['RED'])
  print(OldColor(1))

  print('\ndocstring:')
  print(OldColor.__doc__)
```

##### 実行結果

```sh
deprecated_color.py:19: DeprecationWarning: `OldColor' has moved to `NewColor'
  print(OldColor.RED)
OldColor.RED
deprecated_color.py:20: DeprecationWarning: `OldColor' has moved to `NewColor'
  print(OldColor['RED'])
OldColor.RED
deprecated_color.py:21: DeprecationWarning: `OldColor' has moved to `NewColor'
  print(OldColor(1))
OldColor.RED

docstring:
色
Warning: `OldColor' has moved to `NewColor'.
```

Comment: OldColorは`OldColor=NewColor`で定義されている前提でしょうか？その場合、`OldColor.__getattribute__=lambda ...`のように設定すると、NewColorのメソッドの中身も変わってしまうのではないでしょうか？

Comment: いえ、`OldColor` と `NewColor` は別個に定義されているという前提になります。`OldColor` の定義は `NewColor` と同一にしておく、という事でしょうか？

Comment: なるほど。OldColorとNewColorの中身は同じなので、定義を同一にできないかと思った次第です。とはいえ、別々で定義しても問題ないはずなので、この質問は取り下げさせてください。

Comment: `OldColor(1)`や`OldColor['RED']`で、警告メッセージが出力されるのは、なぜでしょうか？内部的に`__getattribute__`が呼ばれているのでしょうか？